# how to replace an element with a specific index in an array of objects-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects:

```
var arr=[
{name:"d", op: "GTE", field:"ddd"},
{name:"dss", op: "LTE", field:"d4dd"},
{name:"dss", op: "GE", field:"ddddd"}]
```

I have managed to get index of every array in the element, however I'm not sure how to replace the whole object with new values?
ex: at index 2, I want the object to look like this after update:

```
var arr=[
    {name:"d", op: "GTE", field:"ddd"},
    {name:"dss", op: "LTE", field:"d4dd"},
    **{name:"lithe", op: "GE", field:"34545"}**
]
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: What is the change?

Comment: prop - name and field has changed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use simple array access and reassign at the index

```
arr[indexValue] = myNewObject
```

Answer (score 4):

```
arr[2] = {name:"lithe", op: "GE", field:"34545"}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the new element values to replace the existing one in the array.
like:

```
 var newElement = {name:"lithe", op: "GE", field:"34545"};

 arr[2] = newElement;
```

See demo:

```js
var arr = [{
    name: "d",
    op: "GTE",
    field: "ddd"
  },
  {
    name: "dss",
    op: "LTE",
    field: "d4dd"
  },
  {
    name: "dss",
    op: "GE",
    field: "ddddd"
  }
]
console.log("BEFORE");
console.log(arr);

var newElement = {name:"lithe", op: "GE", field:"34545"};

arr[2] = newElement;
/** 
if you need to loop thru the array and find our element, you can do this 

for(var idx=0; idx < arr.length; idx++){
  // any conditional here
  if( idx === 2 ){
     arr[idx] = newElement;
  }
}

*/
console.log("AFTER");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You can hide the snippet to make the answer concise and let readers focus on what's important. Open the snippet editor and scroll to the bottom of the panel on the left, there is a checkbox that says `hide snippet by default`. You can also hide it from the markdown by changing `hide: false` to `hide: true`. I've taken the liberty to do that for you. You can roll back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mention, you can easily directly access and reassign, i.e. `arr[2]={name:"lithe", op: "GE", field:"34545"}`.

However, if you want to be more efficient (i.e. only some fields in the object at `arr[2]` need to be updated, as is your case), it would be better for you to merge your new object with the one that already exists at `arr[2]`. To do so, you may `Object.assign(arr[2], {name:"lithe", field:"34545"})` (ES5), or `arr[2]={...arr[2],...{name:"lithe", field:"34545"}}` (ES6).

Comment: Your ES6 example doesn't work in Chrome 63. `this` is not the object being assigned to, it's the global window object (or whatever the context of the command is).

Comment: @Barmar Good catch! Fixed